# Mac OS X: pushing all traffic through a VMWare VM

Tags: macos, home-networking, vmware-fusion

I want to set up an Astaro (Sophos) UTM in a Virtual Machine.

The Setup should be at the end the following:

```
Cable Modem (one IP adress)
  | [Ethernet]
Sophos UTM (running as VM [VMWare Fusion 5] on the MacMini) 
  | [WIFI]
Airport Express v2 (for sharing Local Network to wireless and wired clients)
1)| [WIFI]   2)| [Ethernet over Thunderbolt Ethernet Adapter]*
Clients     MacMini (Local File Server)

*To have the Mini also protected behind the UTM
```

So the setup process for the UTM works fine, but then the problems start:

1. I just have one external IP (from my cable modem provider)
   ==> So if I put the VM in briged mode my Internet connection drops, because the MacMini also has its IP adress.
2. If I put the VM to NAT mode the Mini itself is not protected by the UTM

So: is there a way to hide the **en0** interface(Ethernet) and the **en1** interface (Wifi) from the MacMini, so that they not even appear in System Preferences Network section but are available to the VM?

That way the Mini must connect to the **en2** interface (Thunderbolt adapter) to make any Internet/LAN connection and I just use the given *single* IP from the Cable Modem.

Thaks for any suggestions...

Sebastian